# Como funciona o "parse" para tratamento de datas em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estou utilizando uma sequência de códigos para aplicar em um `forecasting`:

```
'''
     dataparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%d/%m/%Y')

     df = pd.read_csv('BBSE3.csv', encoding ='utf8', sep=';', parse_dates = 
          ['Data'], index_col = 'Data', date_parser = dateparse)
'''
```

Mas está retornando o seguinte erro:

> ~\Anaconda3\lib_strptime.py in _strptime(data_string, format)
>       360     if not found:
>       361         raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
>   --> 362                          (data_string, format))
>       363     if len(data_string) != found.end():
>       364         raise ValueError("unconverted data remains: %s" %
>
> ValueError: time data '02/01/2018' does not match format 'dd/mm/yyyy'

```
df.head(5) 

Data    Valor
0   2018-02-01  28.7
1   2018-03-01  28.72
2   2018-04-01  28.78
3   2018-05-01  28.97
4   2018-08-01  29.14
```

Inverti a referência de formato de data para `"%Y/%m/%d"`
porém o erro persiste:

> `ValueError: time data '02/01/2018' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d'`

Comment: Ha algum outro problema aí, em partes do seu código ou dados que não estão na pergunta. Se tentarmos aplicar o exemplo que você tem aí, o parse funciona, só com a atda.. Tente adicionar algumas linhas do arquivo CSV na sua pergunta.

Comment: Transformar a coluna **Data** para o formato `datetime` após o carregamento do arquivo seria uma resposta válida para você? Ou a dúvida é exclusiva para o parse dentro do comando `read_csv`?

Comment: @Terry, pode ser durante o carregamento ou após, pensei apenas em fazer durante a carga para agilizar o processo em já estar com os dados no formato adequado para os tratamentos estatísticos que irei realizar. Existe alguma boa prática recomendada neste sentido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu gosto(opinião pessoal) de fazer o parse após o carregamento dos dados por dois motivos: (1) Deixa o código mais legível e (2) com o comando `pd.to_datetime` é possivel tratar erros que podem ocorrer durante a transformação. Tente apenas carregar os dados sem fazer o parse, e após, use o `to_datetime` tratando eventuais erros com o o parâmetro **coerce**(datas inválidas serão setadas como `NaT`):

```
df = pd.read_csv('BBSE3.csv', encoding ='utf8', sep=';')

df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format = '%d/%m/%Y', errors = 'coerce')
df.set_index('Data', inplace = True)
```